# What do you see the utility of invoke function in cypress?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html#Function-with-Arguments

```
cy
  .get('img').invoke('attr', 'src')
    .should('include', 'myLogo')
```

I was trying to understand why do we have the invoke function and how do we understand that we will have to call `.invoke('attr','target')` function and not `.attr('target')` function

Answer (score 2):

So Cypress commands actually do not run synchronously, once they are run to see if the element with that selector is available or not, and we want to call the `.attr` function only when the element is available, so kind we want to wait till the time element becomes available and therefore we have to use the `.invoke()` function.
 Cypress uses jQuery under the hood, but it creates a Cypress wrapper over the jQuery wrapper, so as to wait for a default timeout period or till the time element becomes available, whichever is earlier.

```
cy.get(selector)
```

We cannot call jQuery functions like .attr on Cypress wrappers, so for such thing we call the invoke function with the name of the jQuery function.
However if we use .then() on the Cypress wrapper, then the cb function passed to then will execute when the previous command returns thus it becomes kind of synchronous and we loose the retry-ability of cypress and thus jQuery Command can be called as follows

```
cy
  .get('img').then(image => image.attr('src'invoke('attr', 'src')
    .should('include', 'myLogo')
```